# Coveo Search Word match

Tags: content-search, coveo

In my content, I have the following text

`water engine, Fire engine
Features now available on the test model:
01ANB is the test string`

If I search for `engin` (not engine), it brings up this particular item
but if the search for 1ANB(Not 01ANB) it doesn't bring up this letter, we use `Sitecore 8.1 and coveo 4.0.222.0`
we haven't enabled wildcard search or partial search, below is the markup

```
<div class="CoveoSearchbox"
             data-enable-omnibox="true"
             data-omnibox-timeout="@Model.OmniboxTimeout"
             data-enable-field-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableFieldAddon"
             data-enable-simple-field-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableSimpleFieldAddon"
             data-enable-top-query-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableTopQueryAddon"
             data-enable-reveal-query-suggest-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableRevealQuerySuggestAddon"
             data-enable-query-extension-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableQueryExtensionAddon"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Engin was likely autocorrected to engine because the Coveo Index has detected that it's a simple mistyping of engine. This works with the DidYouMean feature, that allows you to enter a query that is one letter away from a common (enough) word in your index, and automatically corrects it: https://coveo.github.io/search-ui/components/didyoumean.html

As for your second scenario, Coveo does not do partial word match as described in your 01ANB scenario. The solution would be to create computed fields that have stripped the leading zeroes, and to make that field free-text searchable: https://docs.coveo.com/en/677/coveo-for-sitecore-v4/creating-computed-fields

Enabling wildcard search is usually considered a bad idea, as it can slow down the search by 5 to 20 times. Partial match, on the other end, is a Coveo feature that allows a multiple word query to only consider a certain percentage of those words.

I hope this answers your questions.

-Alex